# Tinyint returning as BIT in DatabaseMetaData JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

MySql tinyint is returning as BIT in java and column size is returning as null. For other data types, it is working fine. Any Solution for this?

```
Class clsObj = Class.forName(className);
AbstractEntityPersister classMetadata = (AbstractEntityPersister) getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(clsObj);
String[] properties = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();
String tableName = classMetadata.getTableName();

Map<String, String> dbFieldToPojoFieldMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String prop : properties) {
    String[] names = classMetadata.getPropertyColumnNames(prop);
    dbFieldToPojoFieldMap.put(names[0], prop);
}

DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsColumns = meta.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);

while (rsColumns.next()) {
    Map<String, String> columnMetaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String columnName = rsColumns.getString(Constants.COLUMN_NAME);
    String columnType = rsColumns.getString(Constants.TYPE_NAME);
    String columnSize = rsColumns.getString(Constants.COLUMN_SIZE);
    String decimalDigits = rsColumns.getString(Constants.DECIMAL_DIGITS);
}
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with mysql-connector-java-5.1.46. For me, `.getColumns` returns `TINYINT`,  `3`,  and `0` for `TYPE_NAME`, `COLUMN_SIZE`, and `DECIMAL_DIGITS` respectively. Can you provide a [mcve] along with specific version information (driver version, server version, etc.)?

Comment: What's the MySQL version? What's JDBC driver are you using?

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem. Looks like newer versions of MySQL (namely post 5.0.6, like 8) have defined a `BIT` column type that is an alias for `TINYINT(1)`. Additionally, `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` have been introduced. To resolve this issue for us, we decided to use the java connection string option `"tinyInt1isBit=false"` to get our correctly defined `TINYINT` columns reported correctly. We don't use `BIT`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of @NatFar & @blainwag, I've solved my situation. I also wanted to add an answer for those trying to replicate tables via [ReplicaDB](https://github.com/osalvador/ReplicaDB). By default, it converts `TINYINT` to `BIN` by using `UNHEX()` function. To prevent this you can add the JDBC option at the end of your connection string like this:

```
--source-connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?tinyInt1isBit=false"
```